# Enable/disable statusBar per view on iPhone (20 px issue)

Tags: iphone, ios, statusbar

I just want to **enable/disable** the **status bar per view controller** (some view full screen, some not)

I've been several times through all the post related to the **status bar 20 pixels issue**, but still have the problem, **especially on iOS5.0** (some trick worked on older iOS version):

Here is the problem definition:

- I use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES]` to hide the status bar
- I always have the 20 pixel height white empty area if I do this
- I've try to **enable/disable** the **navigation bar** to force a layout, this does not works on iOS 5:

  ```
  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
  ```
- I've try to manually reset the view frame size, no change

  `self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);`
- I've tried to change manually the navigation container view:

  `self.navigationController.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);`
- All the view are of course 480 pixels height

Comment: so you have a tip @AalokParikh ?

Comment: I use this to show and hide the statusbar `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone];` And also design view according to the statusbar's hidden status ie. If statusbar is hidden I design my View with no statusbar in it. :)

Comment: well, I've tried this too , but the beahvior also is different depending of the iOS version. I've finally had to rewrite completely the navigation framework in order to be 100% sur to manage it...

Comment: Oh I dont get any difference or not been able to detect it sorry :(

Comment: one of hte issue is may be related to the fact that it's a photo app, using the camera framework, this add some degree of complexity I guess when switching from foreground/background

Comment: I also work with same type of app with same framework lol :)

Answer (score 4):

Use the following method in viewWillAppear of view controller to which you would like to display StatusBar.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Declare one BOOL variable to indicate whether status bar is hidden or not while view is loaded in view controller which you would like to hide status bar and set its value to NO.

```
BOOL statusBarHidden = NO;
```

Then add the following code in viewWillAppear of view controller(Status Bar is hidden in this view)

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
if(statusBarHidden == NO)
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectOffset(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame, 0.0, -20.0);
    statusBarHidden = YES;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, You want to hide Status Bar andSet the ViewControllers In Full Screen  With Navigation Bar then use

```
[self.navigationController.view setNeedsLayout];
```

other method  use in you want to hide status Bar....

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];
[self wantsFullScreenLayout];
```

Comment: Please notice that `wantsFullScreenLayout` is deprecated since iOs7... [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/wantsFullScreenLayout)